# Changing image in widget - Kivy - Python

Tags: python, kivy

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image

class Imglayout(FloatLayout):

    def __init__(self,**args):
        super(Imglayout,self).__init__(**args)

        with self.canvas.before:
            Color(0,0,0,0)
            self.rect=Rectangle(size=self.size,pos=self.pos)

        self.bind(size=self.updates,pos=self.updates)
    def updates(self,instance,value):
        self.rect.size=instance.size
        self.rect.pos=instance.pos


class MainTApp(App):

    im=Image(source='img1.jpg')
    def build(self):
        root = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        c = Imglayout()
        root.add_widget(c)


        self.im.keep_ratio= False
        self.im.allow_stretch = True        
        cat=Button(text="Categories",size_hint=(1,.07))
        cat.bind(on_press=self.callback)        
        c.add_widget(self.im)
        root.add_widget(cat);       
        return root

    def callback(self,value):
        self.im=Image(source='img2.jpg')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainTApp().run()
```

What i am trying to do here, is change the image first loaded during object creation, which is shown when the app starts, and then change it when the button cat is pressed. I am trying it to do this way but it isnt happening. I would eventually want it to change with a swipe gesture.(with a little bit of swipe animation like it happens in the phone

what i am trying to build is a slideshow, which will change image in t seconds, unless swiped, and then when a new image comes the timer resets. 
When the category button is pressed the image will not be there and a list of categories to select from. and when an item from the list is touched the images from that list will be displayed on the screen.

And at the end when everything has been done i would want to make it such that it automatically detects categories(based on directories in a specified location.) and then all the images will be available to it.(that is not telling it explicitly how many images and what images.)

But, i am not able to do the first thing, so i would really like some help on that. And maybe a few pointers on how to achieve the other things as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def callback(self,value):
    self.im=Image(source='img2.jpg')
```

Your problem is in the definition of the callback. You create a *new* image with the new source, but you don't do anything with it, like adding it to your widget tree.

What you really want to do is modify the source of the existing image:

```
def callback(self, instance, value):
    self.im.source = 'img2.jpg'
```

This will immediately replace the source of the existing image, which will immediately update in your gui. Note that I also added an instance parameter, which will be passed to the callback so you need to catch it or you'll crash with the wrong number of arguments.

Also, I'd define your image inside build rather than as a class level variable. I'm not sure if the current way will actually cause you problems, but it could in some circumstances.

Comment: Worked your way. using self.im.source. But the thing you said about self,instance,value. It just gives error that callback accepts 3 arguments but only 2 are sent. I have seen on the documentation that there are callbacks with 3 as well as 2 arguments. I couldnt figure out when to apply what :S

Comment: try using `def callback(self, *_)` (if you need those values in the function or `def callback(self, instance= None, value = None)` (if you don't need those values in the function, default values will take place for non matching args